# Java config file issue

Tags: java, swing

I want to change language of display text in java application using eclipse IDE. 
So I am trying to use `resourse=ResourceBundle.getBundle("Text",Locale.ENGLISH );`

but while running getting error as

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't 
find bundle for base name Text, locale en".
```

Can someone help me in solving this. What I understood is I have to get some config file for this, but I not sure from where I can get it.

Please let me know where I can find this file and how to import in project.

Comment: What's your resource bundle file called?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to use a `ResourceBundle` backed by a `Properties` file. This is explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/propfile.html).

It boils down to the following steps:

- Create Java properties files with the correct names (name is based on the Locale)
- Make sure those properties files are located on the class path
- Use `ResourceBundle#getBundle` with the correct name

More information and examples can be found in the official tutorials:

- [Internationalization and Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/) tutorial
- [`ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/concept.html) tutorial
- [`ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) javadoc